# Neo4j OGM - filters combination

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I need to form a dynamic query, using Filter/Filters in neo4j-ogm.
The simplified version of the query may look like this:

```
(A and B and C)
  and (
     (
      (D or E) and not (F or J)
     )  
      or
     (
      (H or I) and not (G or K)
     ) 
     or
    ...... more conditions like this
    )

)
```

I cannot find how to do it using Filters by combining them into logical structures (am I looking not hard enough?).

Is it possible (from implementation looks like Filters are internally maintained as a plain List, which does not allow any precedence etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible with current version.
I ended up 'flatting' the conditions tree into a structure like this:

```
A and B and C and D and not F and not J or 
A and B and C and E and not F and not J or 
A and B and C and H and not G and not K or 
A and B and C and I and not G and not K
```

This is rather ugly and unreadable for debugging purposes, but With AND having precedence over OR, should work.